# PHP subtract a percentage result

Tags: numbers, percentage, subtraction

```
$temp_price_1 = round($price * ((100-$sale_percentage) / 100), 2); $price = $temp_price_1;
```

im using this code to subtract a percentage from a number, for this example my starting number for $price is 24.99 and the $sale_percentage is 50.0 this result is the $temp_price_1 being 12.5 which is correct, however i need it to be 12.50 so it looks like a correct currency value. How do i add the 0 back on the end.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function (returns a string):

```
number_format($price, 2);
```

Will return the string "12.50" when `$price` is set to 12.5